# Do I need a temperature controller?

Tags: temperature

I want to build a food dryer that will work such as when user key in the time and temperature they want, the dryer will heat up as programmed. I need to have Arduino as the microcontroller,an AC heating element and a DC motor of a fan. The questions are:

1) Do I need a temperature controller? If yes, can I connect it directly with Arduino Uno?

Thank you  for helping.

Comment: This q and a told you yes : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/375343/152903

Comment: the arduino would be the temperature controller

Comment: There are complete PID controllers available for very little cost. These have front panels and quite a bit of capability, already. In such a case, there's no need for the Arduino. If you have a complicated recipe to follow that exceeds the ability of these kinds of basic PID controllers, I believe you should document why they are insufficient in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of whether and how to control your temperature depends on several things:

- how accurate must your temperature be?
- how repeatable must a drying session be?
- what is the full temperature range?
- what is the budget for your components?
- what regulatory environment are you designing for? A commercial kitchen?
- how much information about temperature and time do you want to show the user?

These will influence:

- whether you have a temperature sensor, or not
- if your temperature sensor is as simple as a thermistor, or more complex
- the kind of conditioning circuit you need
- whether you have a separate controller, or control integrated in your main MCU, or do not have control at all
- whether your element is on/off-controlled or continuously controlled
- how much math you understand and want to use

If you have no idea about any of the above, a good start would be an on/off element controlled by the Arduino with a thermistor as a sensor.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy a temperature controller with serial communication (eg. RS-485) and let the Arduino talk to it (via the Arduino serial communications connected to an RS-485 driver,  so not exactly directly), or you can try to program the temperature controller functionality in the Arduino code (of course you need to read a sensor for that to work).

Which is better depends on the application requirements, your abilities and budget.